# Proving $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is homeomorphic to unit circle

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $S$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, standard topology. Define the equiv. rel. $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}$ as $x\sim y\iff x - y\in\mathbb{Z}$. I would like to prove that $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $S$.

**Idea:** First, $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is the reals modulo $1$. So define $z\mapsto e^{2\pi i z}$. This is a bijection, and is differentiable, and maps $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ to $S$. So we are done?

Is that enough, or am I making this simpler than it is?

Comment: For homeomorphisms, you need to show the map is continuous, bijective, and has continuous inverse. You haven't really addressed the third of these.

Comment: @πr8 Thank you. So I need to show that if $U\subset [0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, $\exp(2\pi i U)$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$? I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: 1) It needs to be open in the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$, 2) you need to consider all $U\subset \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: When you define a function **always** be explicit about the domain and codomain.

Answer (score 1):

First show that $\Bbb{R}/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]/(0\sim 1)$ (easy). Then use the same exponential map $[0,1]/(0\sim 1) \to S^1$. It is obviously continuous and bijective. Since $[0,1]/(0\sim 1)$ is compact and $S^1$ is Hausdorff, it also has continuous inverse. Therefore it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: There is no need to first prove the first homeomorphism you mention. Why do you think it helps?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez  This is the easiest way I found to show that $\Bbb{R}/\sim$ is compact. And the compactness gives you that the map is open for free.

Comment: The image of [0,1] by the quotient map $R\to R/\sim$ is the whole thing, and the map is continuous.